# Invoke MBean from UC4

Tags: jmx, mbeans, uc4

I want to invoke a **Java MBean** from **UC4**.

I found the below link to call the **MBean** directly from **UC4**, but I do not see an option in **UC4** to create a **JMX Job** (from New Objects).

**https://docs.automic.com/documentation/WEBHELP/English/all/components/AE/10/All%20Guides/Content/ucaccm.htm**

Any pointers or blogs on this could be really helpful.

Comment: Please provide example code.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your UC4 administrator. He/she needs to allow access to the agent from your UC4 client number.  Also, he/she needs to update the variable object named UC_OBJECT_TEMPLATE to include JOBS.JMX.

UC_OBJECT_TEMPLATE exists in client 0000 and may also exist in the client where you are currently logged in.  If it exists in your current client, JOBS.JMX will need to be added to the UC_OBJECT_TEMPLATE in your current client.

Comment: Thanks Reynolds for your reply. I will check with the UC4 administrators on this.